# Cannot connect to any network, ping to 127.0.0.1 returns general failure

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, ethernet, network-adapter, wifi-configuration

I cannot connect to any network (WiFi or Ethernet ) in addition when I ping to 127.0.0.1 returns general failure.

When I try to connect to any network, the status never changes from identifying and in the properties tab I can see that it is sending packages but not receiving.

When I run *ipconfig/renew* from the cmd I receive the message

> An error occurred while renewing interface Ethernet: The system cannot find the file specified

My OS is windows 10.0, I can run xampp with no errors but I cannot access localhost from the browser.

I recently installed OpenVpn and removed it a few hours later. I never configured it or used it.

Comment: Had the same issue, found out that it was because a software named sentinel locked my network completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try resetting your networking.

1.Select the Start button, then select Settings > Network & Internet > Status > Network reset.

2.On the Network reset screen, select Reset now > Yes to confirm.

After that, I don't remember if a reboot is required or not, ...reboot it anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked perfectly. Just what I needed!!