# Unable to open any website following a malicious email. Ping gives correct IP address but results in general failure

Tags: windows-10, dns, internet, internet-connection

Shortly after a malicious email was opened, the internet in the computer in question (running Windows 10) stopped working.

The computer is connected via an ethernet cable, and windows claims it is connected. However, when connecting via wifi, it claims to be connected with no internet. Disconnecting the ethernet cable did not make the connection work via wifi.

I've tried `ipconfig /release`, `renew`, `flushdns`, reinstalling drivers, network reset, restarting the computer...

Finally I've tried `ping`ing a few websites, including one that I'm certain was never tried before on the computer (and all this after flushing the DNS).

It gives me the correct IP but the ping attempts result in `General failure`
(Note: after looking at a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1399108/cannot-connect-to-any-network-ping-to-127-0-0-1-returns-general-failure) I tried pinging 127.0.0.1 and that did not result in a failure)

Finally, I've attempted a `System restore`. When I checked in on it I got a BSOD saying `CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED`. Windows' automatic repair couldn't fix the problem, so I had no choice but to undo it - the computer wouldn't get to the windows log-on screen otherwise.

A virus scan (microsoft defender, full scan) found nothing.

Microsoft edge claims something is blocking access to the network, but I've disabled the firewall and that didn't do anything.

Is there any thing left to attempt before re-installing windows?